# '/home/ron/.npm/bin' not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, .profile

Last night I searched for ways to upgrade node and npm. I copied and pasted some suggestions and upgraded to their stable versions.

I also installed NVM as a forum-user suggested to do.

But this morning when I started Ubuntu, I received the following pop up message:

> Error found when loading /home/ron/.profile
>
> ```
>   /home/ron/.profile line 24: export /home/ron/.npm/bin not a valid identifier
> ```
>
> As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
>   You should fix the problem as soon as feasible."

I also noticed my second monitor is not being recognized by Ubuntu on System Settings.

I am an absolute beginner and started using Ubuntu just a couple of months ago.
I have no clue where to start to fix this issue-Thanks so much for sharing your wisdom.

GNU nano 2.2.6

File: `/home/ron/.profile`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ron/dev/npm/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ron/dev/npm/bin: /home/ron/.npm/bin
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /home/ron/.profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on line 24 of your `~/.profile` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ron/dev/npm/bin: /home/ron/.npm/bin
```

Specifically, it's the space you have here:

```
... /usr/local/games:/home/ron/dev/npm/bin: /home/ron/.npm/bin
                                           ^
                                           |---- Space, bad!
```

So, open that file (run `nano ~/.profile` in a terminal) and remove the space:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ron/dev/npm/bin:/home/ron/.npm/bin
```

While you're at it, you can also remove the 1st of the two `export PATH...` lines. You only need the second.